# How to convert an ip's network segment in Golang?

Tags: go, network-programming

In golang, how can I convert 10.222.1.2/16 to 10.223.1.2/16?
Masks can be considered the same.

For example:

```golang
func Netmap(ip string, dest string) string{}
Netmap("10.222.1.2/16", "10.223.0.0/16") // => "10.223.1.2/16"
Netmap("10.222.1.5/16", "10.224.0.0/16") // => "10.224.1.5/16"
```

==== Update 2023/05/09 ====

** @Volker: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? **

I am very sorry that the previous description is not detailed enough. If the conversion is completed on paper, my thinking is as follows:

[image: my thoughts]

I tried how to implement this process through code, and I found a series of conversion methods that can convert ip to: []byte, uint32, etc.

```golang
ip, ipNet, _ := net.ParseCIDR("10.222.1.2/16")
bytes := []byte(ip)
maskBits := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(ipNet.Mask)
ipBits := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(ip.To4())

prefix, _ := netip.ParsePrefix("10.222.1.2/16")
binary, _ := prefix.Addr().MarshalBinary()
```

But I'm not quite sure what these things mean, and how to manipulate the data.

Thank you very much @Zeke Lu, I'm learning to understand this line of code, I use too few bit operators, and I'm not familiar with them:

```
v := ((v2 >> (32 - bits)) << (32 - bits)) | ((v1 << bits) >> bits)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @wyz see this demo: https://go.dev/play/p/VA0WEli7dPT. Run it and see the output. It should make it easy to understand the bitwise operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net/netip"
)

func Netmap(ip string, dest string) (string, error) {
    v1, bits, err := parse(ip)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    v2, bits2, err := parse(dest)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    if bits2 != bits {
        return "", errors.New("bits not matched")
    }

    // Construct from the high bits from v2 and the low bits from v1.
    v := ((v2 >> (32 - bits)) << (32 - bits)) | ((v1 << bits) >> bits)

    a4 := [4]byte{}
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(a4[:], v)
    addr := netip.AddrFrom4(a4)

    p := netip.PrefixFrom(addr, bits)

    return p.String(), nil
}

// parse parses the prefix and returns the IPv4 address as uint32.
func parse(prefix string) (uint32, int, error) {
    p, err := netip.ParsePrefix(prefix)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, 0, err
    }

    // Let's focus on IPv4.
    if !p.Addr().Is4() {
        return 0, 0, errors.New("unsupported IP version")
    }

    a4 := p.Addr().As4()
    v := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(a4[:])

    return v, p.Bits(), nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Netmap("10.222.1.2/16", "10.223.0.0/16"))
    fmt.Println(Netmap("10.222.1.5/16", "10.224.0.0/16"))
}
```

**Note**: this is not fully tested. Use with caution.